# Bootstrap Popover showing at wrong place upon zoom in/out or resizing Browser window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, position, popover

When I re-size windows of any browser by zooming-in or zooming-out. Popover is not updating position and showing at wrong place.

How do I change the placement/position of Bootstrap Popover upon re-sizing / zooming the browser's window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine in Bootstrap 2.2.1 (unless I am understanding your question wrong). Try the live demo at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals to see if this is what you are looking for. I use onresize event for the window to set the size of the complex modal and its innards correctly.

Comment: Yes! that example is working correctly. My one is on page. How to achieve that via reszie event. Please give some sample code. Thanks

Comment: I think this should do it:
 
     $(window).resize(function () {
     $('#myModal')
                    .css('margin-top', ($('#myModal').outerHeight() / 2) * -1)
                    .css('margin-left', ($('#myModal').outerWidth() / 2) * -1);
     });

Comment: Hmm.. realized that you mean popover, and not modal :-) The sample I gave is for a modal. The idea for the popover would be to reference its position using the element on which it is to be shown. Another easy way is to identify the popovers that are showing at time of resize, close them and open them again (in case they have static text).

Comment: Thanks a lot man but now I don't know how to check that which popover is open or not ... as there can be many many popover ...

Comment: Thanks for guiding towards solution.

`
$(window).resize(function(){
        if ($('.popover').is(":visible")) {
          $('#azeem').popover('show');
        }
    });
`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re-position it myself with `offset().top` and `outerHeight()` but ran into issues.  The solution for me was to simply recall the popover's `show` event again:

```
    $(window).off("resize").on("resize", function() {
        $(".popover").each(function() {
            var popover = $(this);
            if (popover.is(":visible")) {
                var ctrl = $(popover.context);
                ctrl.popover('show');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work on the page which has multiple popovers as it displays all popvers on window resize

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to provide example code to show what you mean.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.